# How can I get access to the original records when joining Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a working Kafka Streams app, that is currently creating two KStreams from two different topics.  That part is working just fine.

Now, I want to join them, and get an "aggregated-record" of the value in the first, and the value in the second one.  The keys are simple Java strings, and the values are avro-encoded GenericRecords.

Based on the documentation, I should be able to do something like this:

```
    KStream<String, GenericAvroSerde> joined =
        inputTopicStartKStream.leftJoin(inputTopicEndKStream,
        (left, right) -> { ??? }
        JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(24)),
        Joined.with(
            stringSerde,
            genericAvroSerde,
            genericAvroSerde)
    );
```

However, it's not clear from the docs or tutorials I found online what can I do in the section above that says `{ ??? }`.  I've tried multiple variations of the above, with no luck.  I'm using Kakfa Streams 2.2.0 version, if it matters.

I simply want to have an output stream of `<key, merge value1 + value2>`, for records that come down on both of the streams with the same key.  I can do the merging of the values manually, but it's not clear how to even get access to the values on the right side of the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ValueJoiner `(left, right) -> { ??? }` , **left** represents value from left stream and **right** represents value from right stream

All you have to do is, add your code in ValueJoiner like below:

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;

KStream<String, GenericAvroSerde> joined =
    inputTopicStartKStream.leftJoin(inputTopicEndKStream,
    (left, right) -> {
             // You can get access to the generic Avro record by
             // casting both left and right values 
             Record leftRecord = (Record) left;
             Record rightRecord = (Record) right;

             // For the original question, you can simply create a new GenericRecord 
             // with the contents of left and right records
             GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
             record.put("left", left);
             record.put("right", right);
    }
    JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(24)),
    Joined.with(
        stringSerde,
        genericAvroSerde,
        genericAvroSerde)
);
```